# Xamarin Forms call function on property change

Tags: mobile, xamarin

I'm New to xamarin and Xamarin forms.
i wonder if i can call a function in my Content page when Entry.IsFocused
i need to make a different Control to show up or disappear according to the property change
  is it possible in Xamarin Forms
Thanks
Shimon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a ViewModel that holds a `bool` value. Let's call it `IsEntryFocused`.
Bind the control to your ViewModel's property. For example:

```
entry.SetBinding(TextView.IsFocused, new Binding("IsEntryFocused", BindingMode.TwoWay));
```

In addition to that bind the same ViewModel's property to the `IsVisible` property of a different control. For example:

```
label.SetBinding(TextView.IsFocused, new Binding("IsEntryFocused"));
```

Now `label` appears when `entry` has got the focus on it.

This exampe is based on the MVVM pattern. For a short introduction in Xamarin.Forms read this: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/